# How to fallback to out-of-site login server - ActiveDirectory

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain, windows-server-2012

I pretty much spend all of my time on Linux\Networking however I am trying to set up a multi-site AD configuration.  There is no root site or anything like that, I simply have two DCs in SiteA and one DC in SiteB.  They all replicate to each other.

I am physically in SiteB.  Before I actually set up the sites in Active Directory Sites and Services my test machine would bounce between `SiteB-DC01`, `SiteA-DC01`, and `SiteA-DC02`.  After setting this up (both sites and subnets) my SiteA machines are using the SiteA DCs and my SiteB machines are using my SiteB DCs.  I confirm this by issuing an `echo %LOGONSERVER%`.

This is all well and good but....

What happens when SiteB's DC goes down?  To simulate this I took down SiteB's DC and the clients in SiteB complained that `No logon server could be found`.

I have tried creating an additional `_ldap SRV` record in `Forward Lookup Zones->DOMAIN->_sites->SiteB->_tcp` to no avail.  I set the priority of the SiteB DC as 0 and the SiteA DC as 1.  Is this the correct way to do this?

Additionally, what are the differences between all of the different SRV record locations?  I couldn't find much documentation  I have:

- DOMAIN->Sites->SITE_HERE->_tcp
- DOMAIN->_tcp
- _msdcs.DOMAIN->dc->_sites->SITE_HERE->_tcp
- _msdcs.DOMAIN->dc->_tcp

Common sense would tell me the client (it knows what site it's in since it's in the registry) would do a site-specific DNS query to locate all of the DCs and then choose one to auth with based upon the priorities and weights.

Comment: Your clients... do they use other DNS resolvers besides just the domain controller that you took offline?  The redundancy in Active Directory does no good if your clients have no DNS server with which to locate an alternate domain controller...

Comment: @RyanRies - That did it.  I forgot to add the second DC as a secondary DNS server.  What is the best practice for this?  Should you be adding all of your DCs as DNS servers?  Create an answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clients... do they use other DNS resolvers besides just the domain controller that you took offline? The redundancy in Active Directory does no good if your clients have no failover DNS server with which to locate an alternate domain controller...

Personally, I would recommend configuring all your domain members to use two domain controllers in their own site first, and then a domain controller from an adjacent site as a tertiary DNS resolver.  (The benefits in using additional DNS resolvers after the third one drop off sharply, in my opinion.) In production I would recommend two domain controllers per site, but of course in a lab or development environment it's understandable to see just one DC per location.

Generally speaking, I would advise against manually creating SRV records for domain controllers in Active Directory. The DCs in a healthy environment should be registering and maintaining their own SRV records.

There does exist an "auto site coverage" feature of Active Directory where, when AD sees a site that contains no domain controllers, DCs from adjacent sites will "helpfully" register their own SRV records in that other site as well in attempt to provide coverage for clients that may be in that site... I put "helpfully" in quotation marks because the feature can cause confusion if you wonder how the records got there.

> Additionally, what are the differences between all of the different SRV record locations?

The _msdcs.forestname.com zone is replicated forest-wide, and contains SRV records that clients can use to locate domain services throughout the forest, such as LDAP, Global Catalogs, KDCs, etc.

The _msdcs subzone that is underneath the domainname.forestname.com zone, the one with a "greyed out" icon, is a delegated subzone. It's delegated to that domain specifically. If you have a single-domain forest, you probably won't see much difference, but it's a lot easier to see the difference in a multi-domain forest with a complex DNS structure.